# el ultimo articulo borrado del carrito se guarda en el local storage cuando actualizo la pagina

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo un proyecto de un ecomerce para mi escuela y ya tengo casi todo listo, pero cuando borro todo del carrito de compras y actualizo la pagina el ultimo articulo que borre esta en mi carrito de compras,

este es mi codigo js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    if(localStorage.getItem("newCart")) {
        cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("newCart")) || []
        upDateCart()
    }
})
stock.forEach((stock) => {
    const div = document.createElement('div')
    div.classList.add("col-md-1")
    div.innerHTML = `
    <button id="agregar${stock.id}" class="button">Agregar a carrito</button>
`
    container.appendChild(div)
    const button = document.getElementById(`agregar${stock.id}`)

    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    addToCart(stock.id)
    })

})

const upDateCart = () => {
    cartContainer.innerHTML = ""

    cart.forEach((prod) => {
        const div = document.createElement("div")
        div.className = ("cart-review-cotainer")
        div.innerHTML = `
        <div class="col-md-5 d-flex flex-column  justify-content-between">
            <div>
                <p id="cart-item-name">${prod.item}</p>
                <p id="cart-item-price">${prod.precio}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 delete-container">
            <button onclick="deleteItem(${prod.id})" id="delete-item"><img class="delete-img" src="./images/trash-solid.svg" alt=""></button>
        </div>
        `
        cartContainer.appendChild(div)

       localStorage.setItem("newCart", JSON.stringify(cart))
       console.log(cart)
       
    })
    total.innerText = cart.reduce((acc, prod) => acc + prod.precio, 0)
}
```

aqui es donde agrego y elimino los articulos de mi carrito, y cuando elimino el ultimo articulo de mi carrito y actualizo mi pagina mi carrito siempre tiene el ultimo objeto eliminado

```
    function addToCart(prodId) {
    const item = stock.find((prod) => prod.id === prodId);
    cart.push(item);
    upDateCart()
}

const deleteItem = (prodId) => {
    const item = cart.find((prod) => prod.id === prodId)
    const index = cart.indexOf(item)
    cart.splice(index, 1)
    upDateCart()
    console.log(cart)
}
```